Logitech mouse G102 and keyboard G610 irresponsive after replugin on Windows 11

I see the following error in the device manager:


Windows cannot start this hardware device because its configuration information (in the registry) is incomplete or damaged. To fix this problem you should uninstall and then reinstall the hardware device. (Code 19)


Restarting the machine can solve the issue but it's annoying to reopen applications.

And the devices are usable only when they are plugged in before starting the machine.

Logitech G HUB doesn't help.

My non-Logitech devices have no such issue.

This issue seems to have arisen after a Windows 11 system update.



Have you tried rolling back the update? When you say the G Hub doesn't help, do you mean you reinstalled it, or used some feature in it? Have you checked for and updated drivers?

I don't know what's the specific system update possibly causing the issue. And I also don't know how to roll back. After installing G Hub, the Code 19 error is still there. The drivers are already up to date I think. In the device manager, "Update Drivers" shows that they are already the best drivers. And I see no newer drivers in Windows Update also.

Disconnect the device. Uninstall the Logitech software. Find the device in Device Manager and delete it. If you're prompted, tell the computer to delete/uninstall the drivers too. Then restart your computer and reconnect the device. When we mention reinstalling the device drivers, that usually also means going to the vendor support site and downloading the latest available drivers manually, rather than relying on the various automated tools or driver installers.

Finally found out it's Spacedesk causing the issue, thanks to Strazza02's investigation in this Reddit post.
The solution is just installing the latest version of Spacedesk.
